# Cannot launch android studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-18.04

I am unable to launch Android Studio on Ubuntu. How do I fix this?

This the error message:

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx7800m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `-Xmx:7800m`, that said, the defaults are quite sensible and there's little benefit to setting Xmx.